# backbone template won't stay in html

Tags: javascript, html, templates, backbone.js

so I have a backbone template I'm inserting in my html:

```
<div class = "outside of template">
<script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="view1">
      <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">   
      <input class="view" style="border:none;" value="<%= name %> <%= age %> - <%= occupation %>">
      <a class = "destroy"  />
    </div>  
    </script>
</div>
```

but when I run my script/ open my page, the output of the template always appear
underneath my

```
<div class = "outside of template"></div>
```

so how can I make the template contents stay within my html div or table or whatever element?

Comment: close the </div> before the <script> tags ?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/PGpLF/ It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Template` appears to be between the `div` element. That's your issue right there.

It has to be:

```
<div class = "outside of template"></div>
<script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="view1">
      <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">   
      <input class="view" style="border:none;" value="<%= name %> <%= age %> - <%= occupation %>">
      <a class = "destroy"  />
    </div>  
</script>
```